# Google Script GetCell value - Send to API

Tags: json, api, google-sheets-api

Here is what I'm trying to do:

Insert the displayed value of a google sheet cell into the "message" portion of an API script. I have a script that successfully runs, gets the value of a particular cell and sends it to the device that the API controls. The issue is that it only sends the first letter or number of the contents of the cell (instead of sending "1234" it just sends "1"). Here is the scripting I'm using. Any advice on how to get it to return/send the entire contents of the specified cell?

```
function myFunction() {
 var celldata = getcell()
 var data = {
 'slot_id':  '1234',
 'token' : '123456',
 'message' : getcell ('getcell'),
}

var payload = JSON.stringify(data)  

var url = 'https://www.flapit.com/control/slot';
var options = {
'method': 'post',
'contentType': 'application/json', 
'payload' : payload,
}

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

}

function getcell(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
 var getcell = sheet.getRange("k3").getValue()
 return getcell [0]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:
 return getcell [0]

Try:  return getcell

The value returned by sheet.getRange("k3").getValue() is a string, not an array.

Comment: It worked! I was making it too complicated. - Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help!